# Do something if element children has url link like

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, indexof

I need some ideias or sugestions to achive this:
I have a breadcrumb in my prestashop website, and i want to manipulate to show a div if the breadcrumb contains url equals or contains "this-particular-text"...

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf("text-to-find") > -1) {
    console.log("Hello world!");
}
```

```html
<div id="breadcrumb">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="breadcrumbs space-padding-tb-10 breadcrumbs-left">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-links"> 
          <a class="home" href="https://home.com" title="back to start">Start</a> 
          <span class="navigation-pipe">&gt;</span> 
          <span class="navigation_page">
          <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
            <a itemprop="url" href="https://home.com/text-to-find" title="text to find">
              <span itemprop="title">text to find</span>
            </a>
          </span>
          <span class="navigation-pipe">&gt;</span>
          <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
            <a itemprop="url" href="https://home.com/other-text" title="other text">               <span itemprop="title">other text</span>
            </a>
            </span>
            <span class="navigation-pipe">&gt;</span>Another Text</span></div></div></div></div></div>
<div id="showthis" style="display:none;"> I wanna show this div if id breadcrumb contains on his children a href with https://home.com/text-to-find </div>
```

I can only control with indexOf (the only thing that i could remember...)

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("text-to-find") > -1) {
    document.getElementById('breadcrumb').style.display = 'none';
}
```

?

Comment: No sorry, i only put console.log just to know what i'm getting ... the website is live, the right div is document.getElementById('showthis').style.display = 'none';
...but i can't use indexOf window.location because other url i wanna show this div...
bottom is if breadcrumb nested inner a children has the link or title text to find i show the div #showthis else display:none...